# Why am I getting Syntax error in "list.sort()"

Tags: python

```
t,n=map(int,token[:2])
list=[]
for i in xrange(2,t):
    list.append(string(n=int(token[i]))

list.sort()
print list
```

I am getting syntax error in 6th line.Why is it so?

Comment: What error does it show

Comment: @Ujjayanta you have to tick the right answer if the community has helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Error- List is a Keyword .Use something else

Second Error - Close the bracket in the list.append statment

```
>>list=[1,2,4,3]
>>list
>>[1,2,4,3]
>>list.sort()
>>list
>>[1,2,3,4]
```

Apparently The First error is not an error but as the old folks say It's not a good practice to use the keywords

Comment: using keywords such as `list` as a variable should not be prefered, but its not an error

Comment: `list` is not a keyword. It is only a built-in name, so you are not prohibited from using it as a name for your own variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need add one closing bracket for append method

Answer (score 1):

It is because, you have forgot one closing bracket at end of `append()` method.
Your code should be.

```
t,n=map(int,token[:2])
list=[]
for i in xrange(2,t):
    list.append(string(n=int(token[i]))) # Here I have added closing bracket

list.sort()
print list
```